# Ldap query Trying to use group search and user search in same query but its not working,

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

```
ldapsearch -x -h <domain> -b "(&(cn=users,dc=apple,dc=com)(cn=groups,dc=apple,dc=com))" -s sub -LLL
```

Trying to use group search and user search in the same query but it's not working, suggest what is wrong or how it can be done.

I tried multiple query

```
ldapsearch -x -h nod.apple.com -b "(|(cn=users)(cn=groups))",dc=apple,dc=com -s sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only make a search request to one base to a DSA (LDAP Server).

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h <domain> -b "dc=apple,dc=com" -s sub "(|(objectclass=group)(Objectclass=user"))
```

You can "Google/Bing" for ldapsearch examples or read https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch

-jim